# LeafletJS How to fit every Layer in ViewPort?

Tags: leaflet

I have a non-geographical map and I would like to fit every Shape into the viewport.

My code so far:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            renderer: L.canvas()
        });

xhr.onload = function () {

  if (xhr.status !== 200) return
  var layer = L.geoJSON(xhr.response).getBounds();
  mymap.fitBounds(layer);

  L.geoJson(xhr.response, {style: style}).addTo(mymap);

        };
```

One of my maps is just to big, screenshot attached.
Could someone lead me into the right direction with that problem?

[image]

Edit: okay got it, map takes an zoom parameter, I just pass -5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [Leaflet tutorial for non geographical maps](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html), you can simply use the map [`minZoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-minzoom) option with a *negative* value to enable your map to be zoomed out further.

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  renderer: L.canvas(),
  minZoom: -5
});
```

Comment: Got this but is there a way to fit my map in viewport automatically? At the moment I do this like this, but it's still zoomed to close. My z variable get -1, -2 would be perfect: var bounds = L.geoJSON(xhr.response).getBounds(); var z = mymap.getBoundsZoom(bounds, true);
   var center = bounds.getCenter();
   mymap.setView(center, z);

Comment: Sounds like you should add some padding to your bounds.